# C++ : Returning a vector from a function

Tags: c++, arrays, function, vector, return-value

I have tried to find a solution to this problem but so far I have not found one that helps my situation. I am writing a program that allows a user (target audience being a teacher) to enter grades for four different grade categories. I decided to use vectors to accomplish this since they seem more flexible than arrays. My main problem is getting a vector in my main function to be equal to a vector that I filled in a function. Here is some of the code that is giving me problems:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

vector<int> getGrades(string);

int main()
{
    string gradetype;
    vector<int> lab;
    vector<int> test;
    vector<int> project;
    vector<int> final_exam;
    int i = 0;
    cout << "Welcome to Grade Portal 4.0\n";
    cout << "Please enter the grade type followed by the\n";
    cout << "grades for the grade type.\n";
    cout << "The choice are: \n";
    cout << "Lab\n";
    cout << "Test\n";
    cout << "Project\n";
    cout << "Final\n";
    cout << "These can be entered in any order\n";
    cout << "Enter 'Q' at any time to quit\n";
    cout << "--------------------------------------------------\n";

    do
    {
        cout << "Enter grade type: ";
        getline(cin, gradetype);
        if (gradetype == "lab")
        {
            lab = getGrades(gradetype);
            i++;
        }
        else if (gradetype == "test")
        {
            test = getGrades(gradetype);
            i++;
        }
        else if (gradetype == "project")
        {
            project = getGrades(gradetype);
            i++;
        }
        else if (gradetype == "final")
        {
            final_exam = getGrades(gradetype);
            i++;
        }

        else if (gradetype == "q")
        {
            i = 5;
        }
        else
            cout << "You shoudlnt be seeing this\n";
        cin.ignore();
    }while (i < 4);
}
vector<int> getGrades(string gradetype)
{
    int gradeN;
    vector<int> grades;
    int grade;
    cout << "How many grades do you have to enter?: ";
    cin >> gradeN;

    for (int i = 0; i < gradeN; i++)
    {
        cin.ignore();
        cout << gradetype << " grade: ";
        cin >> grade;
        grades.push_back(grade);
    }
    return grades;
}
```

My code is prettty much in pieces right now because of all the editing I've been doing but I pulled out the parts that I believe the problem is coming from. If I use loops to display the contents of the vectors such as "lab" or "test" in the main function, the contents are incorrect. The contents of the new vectors SHOULD be whatever grades the user inputted. Instead, I get different numbers.
For example, I entered the following information and got some very strange output:
2 grades for each grade type, each grade was a "99" (contents of each vector should be 99, 99)
With a for-loop, I printed out the contents of the vectors and got the following:
lab vector - (3351064, 3351064) | 
test vector - (0, 0) |
project vector - (1983462368, 1983462368) |
final exam vector - (1982745200, 1982745200) |
I have the number of elements that should be in the vectors correct, but the numbers are very incorrect. According to my sample input, the contents of all of these vectors should be 99, 99

I feel as if the problem is with setting the contents of say the "lab" vector equal to the contents of the vector "grades" created in the function getGrades. I am not getting any build errors or warnings and the code executes successfully, just with unanticipated outcomes. I'm sure its something small I have looked over but I have not been able to solve this for the life of me. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), because the program you show now won't build. Also please elaborate on the problem you're having, are you getting build errors? Run-time errors (crashes)? Unexpected results? If you get build errors, then please show us the build errors (in full, complete and unedited). If you get crashes, use a debugger to locate the crash in your code. If you get unexpected results, then show us the actual and expected output.

Comment: I'm also a bit curious about those `cin.ignore()` calls, why do you need them?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg, The one in `main` actually negates the leftover newline from `getGrades` (though it's not a very intuitive link to follow). The one in `getGrades` is unnecessary.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. But I still don't really understand what problem you are having. You have a function that returns a vector of integers, and you call that function, assigning the result to a vector of integers. That should work just fine.

Comment: Break the problem down. Returning a vector from a function (what you report as the problem) has nothing to do with reading from standard input into a vector.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg thanks for the pointers, I added in some more information about the problem I was having. As chris had mentioned, I put the `cin.ignore()` in the main function because the program would always display the "else" message after the `getGrades` function ran through

Comment: After some modification in your code to print the vector in `getGrades` and for `"lab"` selection, [I can't really replicate your problem](http://ideone.com/isVuU1).

Comment: @juanchopanza I am not sure I know what you are trying to get me to look at. When I display the contents of the vectors in the `getGrades` function itself, the contents is correct. However, the contents of the `lab`, `test`, `project`, and `final_exam` vectors are not correct after returning the value for the `grades` vector from `getGrades`

Comment: @FromLifesFirstCry Can you show us *how* you check the vectors?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Putting the loops inside the `getGrades` function and inside the `if` statement displays the correct values for me as well. It was only when I outputted the contents outside of the `do-while` loop where the results were inaccurate. Perhaps this means there is a problem with how I am setting up my `do-while` loop?

Comment: @FromLifesFirstCry Updated [my test program](http://ideone.com/isVuU1) and it still works fine. It seems to indicate that there's something else that wrong. Do you have shadowing variable declarations in your actual program, so you have e.g. two variables with the name `lab`? Do the compiler give you any warnings? If you enable more warnings, do you get any then?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Finally figured it out! I was checking the vectors incorrectly. I accidentally mixed some C++98 with some C++11 and was using a range-based loop while displaying the contents by `cout << lab[c] << endl;` with `c` as my const int.